# Please explain this while-loop

Tags: programming

Code:

```
keygen[keybitlength_] := 
Module[{kbl, kbl1, pPrime, qPrime, nKey, phiOFn, eKey, dKey},
kbl = 2^(keybitlength/2);
kbl1 = 2^(keybitlength/2 - 1);
pPrime = RandomPrime[{kbl1, kbl}];
qPrime = RandomPrime[{kbl1, kbl}];
nKey = pPrime*qPrime;
phiOFn = (pPrime - 1) (qPrime - 1);
While[eKey = RandomPrime[{2, phiOFn}]; ! CoprimeQ[eKey, phiOFn]];
dKey = PowerMod[eKey, -1, phiOFn];
{{eKey, nKey}, {dKey, nKey}}]
```

The part I don't understand is this (specifically the While statement. to me it seems like it lacks a body?):

```
While[eKey = RandomPrime[{2, phiOFn}]; ! CoprimeQ[eKey, phiOFn]];
dKey = PowerMod[eKey, -1, phiOFn];
{{eKey, nKey}, {dKey, nKey}}]
```

While eKey is a random Prime between 2 and phiOFn and not Coprime with phiOFn?
To my knowledge eKey and phiOfN should be Coprime for RSA encryption to work.

Answer (score 6):

The While statement can indeed be used with only a condition. Obviously, `While[True]` is an infinite loop, `While[False]` immediately stops, but it may make sense when the evaluation of the condition can be different in each cycle. For example

```
While[n=RandomInteger[{1, 1000}]; Mod[n,100] != 0]; n
```

computes n until it ends on two zeros.

In your example eKey is computed until eKey and phiOFn are coprime.